# PayPal Sandbox history redirects to REAL history

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

In the new PayPal Sandbox, we want to test the IPN, with a `payment_status` of `denied`.

The old PayPal sandbox used to allow us to view the transaction history and Accept/Deny a transaction.

Seems the new Sandbox account hierarchy seems to be confused. When clicking History it redirects back to the REAL `paypal.com` site, not `sandbox.paypal.com`, and hence shows the wrong history.

Steps to reproduce:

1. log via developer.paypal.com
2. go to "Enter sandbox site" under Applications, now logged into https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com with the correct account showing, great
3. Click history, redirected to https://history.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_history, which shows the REAL history. Grrr.

Any ideas? Happy for a hack, just want to fire a deny request for a sandbox transaction so we can test.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue - sorry. Trying to change the URL to the Sandbox one still redirects you to the Live site and, occasionally for whatever reason, a security certificate page. A fix is coming soon.

If you want to be updated on the issue as it goes on you create a ticket at PayPal.com/mts, let me know what the ticket number is, and I can grab it.

Edit: 
This should be resolved now. I cleared my cache and cookies, closed the browser, and tried it out. I was able to view the transaction history in the Sandbox.

Comment: Same issue. My ticket number is #130606-000224

Answer (score 0):

we're having the same issue on our end. What works for us is firing up an incognito window in Google Chrome and login via there. It's a hack, but it works.