# Paypal Sandbox Merchant Account History Tab Redirects To Main Paypal

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I am facing issue in viewing my sandbox's merchant history. Had tried to search on google but was not able to resolve my issue.
When I try to check my Merchant A/c history its getting redirect to main Paypal site every time. 
But when I check for my Personal A/c history is working fine.
Did anyone faced this issue?
Could anyone please guide me where I am going wrong.

Regards
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

It is part of a known issue mentioned here: 
[PayPal Sandbox history redirects to REAL history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954520/paypal-sandbox-history-redirects-to-real-history)

I'll be updating that thread when the problem is resolved. You can also create a ticket and mention the ticket number on that thread, I'll grab it, and keep you posted as it goes on.

Comment: Thanks @PayPal_Patrick.
Yes I will raise the ticket and update on that thread. 
Thanks once again.